# Comprobación de numero narcisista

Tags: c

espero estén bien, necesito de vuestro consejo para poder solucionar un inconveniente que tengo en mi código, el propósito es descubrir si el numero que ingrese el usuario es narcisista o no, mi problema esta en la parte de la comprobación, ya que no me muestra el resultado que espero.

Se dice que un numero narcisista es aquel que es igual a la suma de cada uno de sus dígitos elevados a la **"n"** potencia (donde **"n"** es el número de cifras del número) y es por eso que ocupe un if para poder comparar, pero no me funciona, quisiera saber si hay otro método para poder comparar el resultado con el numero que se ingreso inicialmente.

**Como por ejemplo:**

El **153** es un número narcisista puesto que:1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int contarDigitos(int num){
int Contador, num2,operacion;
        num2 = num;
        Contador = 0;
        while(num != 0){
            Contador++;
            num=(num / 10);
        }
    printf("La cantidad de digitos del Numero [%d] es = %d \n",num2,Contador);
        operacion=pow(num2,Contador);                                   //Aqui es donde pretendo hacer la comprobacion
        if (operacion=num2)                                             //Para saber si el numero que ingresen es narcisista o no.
        {                                                               
            printf("\n El numero %d es narcisista \n",operacion);
            }
        else
            {
                printf("\n El numero no es narcisista.\n");
            }
 }
int main(void)
{
    int num,op1;

    do
    {
        printf("\n Programa para saber si un numero es narcisista");
        printf("\n              Menu                            ");
        printf("\n 1. Verificar si el numero es narcisista.");
        printf("\n 2. Salir.");
        printf("\n ~~~~~~> ");
        scanf("%d",&op1);
        switch (op1)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\n Por favor ingrese el numero a evaluar.");
                printf("\n ~~~~~> ");
                scanf("%d",&num);
                contarDigitos(num);
                system("pause");
        }
    } while (op1!=2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No sabía que a eso le llamaban números narcisistas. Hoy aprendí algo nuevo 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes varios inconvenientes en el código. Uno de ellos es que dentro de la comparación estás haciendo una asignación, por tanto siempre da que el número es narcisista, tienes que usa el comparador `==` dentro del `if (operacion=num2)`.

Por otra parte, no estás haciendo la sumatoria de la potencia de cada digito, entonces nunca te va a dar bien si es o no. Para que funcione bien tienes que iterar sobre cada digito como en la línea 21 del siguiente código.

```c
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int contarDigitos(int num)
{
  int cantidad_digitos, num2, operacion;
  num2 = num;
  cantidad_digitos = 0;
  while (num2 != 0)
  {
    cantidad_digitos++;
    num2 = (num2 / 10);
  }

  printf("La cantidad de digitos del Numero [%d] es = %d \n", num, cantidad_digitos);

  // Suma cada digito del numero elevado a la cantidad de digitos del numero
  num2 = num;
  int total_suma = 0;
  while (num2 != 0) {
    int digito = num2 % 10;
    total_suma += pow(digito, cantidad_digitos);
    num2 /= 10;
  }

  // Si la sumatoria es igual al numero, entonces es narcisita
  if (total_suma == num)
  {
    printf("\n El numero %d es narcisista \n", num);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\n El numero no es narcisista.\n");
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int num, op1;

  do
  {
    printf("\n Programa para saber si un numero es narcisista");
    printf("\n              Menu                            ");
    printf("\n 1. Verificar si el numero es narcisista.");
    printf("\n 2. Salir.");
    printf("\n ~~~~~~> ");
    scanf("%d", &op1);
    switch (op1)
    {
    case 1:
      printf("\n Por favor ingrese el numero a evaluar.");
      printf("\n ~~~~~> ");
      scanf("%d", &num);
      contarDigitos(num);
      system("pause");
    }
  } while (op1 != 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo.